# Javascript simple pop up on all site collection pages in MOSS 2007

Tags: javascript, 2007, custom-action

I would like to display popup for all site collection pages. Limitation is I am not allowed to touch master page.
I do know we can do it with custom action in 2010 with scriptsrc attribute but it is not available in MOSS 2007.

Can anyone tell me how can I inject javascript on all pages without altering master page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of delegate control feature. Refer this link for more information [Delegate Control](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/06/using-delegate-control.html)

Delegate control is alternative to master page / page layouts.

Comment: Can you mark the response as answer. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit all the page layout for each site to add the popup.

Comment: any other approach other this in your mind ?

Comment: custom coding allowed ? i mean features ....

Comment: Yes it allowed.